# Android - Get GraphView datapoint x y location

Tags: android, graphing, android-graphview, datapoint

I'm using [jjoe64's](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView) awesome GraphView for Android. At the moment I'm trying to determine 2 things:

1. Is it possible, once plotted, to get a DataPoint's x,y location values?
2. Also, is it possible to get that location in the onTap call?

I'm trying to show a custom view just above the data point (tapped or otherwise); hence the reason I need it's coordinates. I know how to get the x,y position of a user touch, but the issue is I also need the value from the datapoint.

From what I can tell the DataPoint and DataPointInterface do not have an accessible x,y location value - only x,y double values (non-location related).

I was hoping for something like:

```
    DataPoint p = series.getPoint(n);
    int x = p.getXLocation();
    int y = p.getYLocation();
```

Where n is either the exact position in the series (like getting something from an ArrayList) or n represents the non-location x value given to the DataPoint upon creation (new DataPoint(**double x**, double y)).

Has anyone else using this library solved this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I can see that the method `findDataPoint(float x, float y)` exists in the BaseSeries class but it's protected, so I cannot access it from my LineGraphSeries object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424505/how-to-add-tap-listener-on-data-point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up subclassing BaseSeries and basically doing a complete replication of LineGraphSeries with the exception of making some of those protected functions public. This gave me the ability to keep track of datapoints and their PointF's in a Map, then look up PointF's based on their corresponding datapoint.

Answer (score -1):

```
views.setOnDataPointTapListener(new OnDataPointTapListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onTap(Series series, DataPointInterface dataPoint) {
                                            Toast.makeText(graph.getContext(), "Data : On Data Point clicked: "+dataPoint, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }
                                    });
```

I found this to show data-points.Its quite easy as you can see.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but the onTap method does not provide the x,y coordinates of the datapoint; it only provides the x,y values you provided it at instantiation. Please read original question. I'm looking for the datapoints' on-screen location.

Comment: what is 'views' ? Copying and pasting code with no context and declaring that it is "quite easy" is not very helpful.

Comment: check this out if its any help http://www.android-graphview.org/documentation/tap-listener-on-data-points