# How to add tap listener on data point?

Tags: java, android, android-graphview

I want to a add tap listener on a data point in the graph view in `Android Studio`.

There is a problem in my java code that says: can't resolve method `get Activity()` in last line of codes.

Help me resolve my problem.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.graph;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;

import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPointInterface;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.OnDataPointTapListener;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.PointsGraphSeries;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.Series;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
        LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(0, -2),
            new DataPoint(1, 5),
            new DataPoint(2, 3),
            new DataPoint(3, 2),
            new DataPoint(4, 6)
        });
        graph.addSeries(series);
        graph.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.background_color));
        series.setThickness(5);
        graph.getViewport().setScalable(true);
        graph.getViewport().setScrollable(true);

        PointsGraphSeries<DataPoint> series2 = new PointsGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(0, -2),
            new DataPoint(1, 5),
            new DataPoint(2, 3),
            new DataPoint(3, 2),
            new DataPoint(4, 6)
        });
        graph.addSeries(series2);
        series2.setColor(Color.RED);
        series2.setSize(10);
        series2.setOnDataPointTapListener(new OnDataPointTapListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTap(Series series2, DataPointInterface dataPoint) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Series1: On Data Point clicked: "+dataPoint, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: use getApplicationContext() instead of getActivity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `OnDataPointTapListener` is an anonymous class, inside this class the method `getActivity` does not exist, but it does exits within your Activity. You should use the `this` from your `MainActivity` not this from your `OnDataPointTapListener`:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this.getActivity(), "Series1: On Data Point clicked: "+dataPoint, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: MainActivity.this is also worked for me, I couldn't understand MainActivity.this.get Activity() part btw.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of getActivity put MainActivity.this

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Series1: On Data Point clicked: "+dataPoint, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.